# I need to fetch access token from the Url in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got the access token as a response from the server in **Oauth2.0**, but i am not able to fetch it into my code. Could anybody help me giving the code in C# or help just giving some part of it?

Comment: We need to see your code and the format that you are getting the response. Is it coming back [like this?](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/). You may just need to de-serialize it using Newtonsoft.Json or something and extract the value. Hard to say with what we know here.

Comment: @KSib Format  :- 
http://176.66.102.44:8088/#access_token=eHwAIJd%40bo657tdv8XSaS6hYU%40Ov/XiOWBlMdwo4/h63Q1E%40RcJukIbBnDU%40dh/AYJnEQc4/WmTrUCN3snAntvmchEpZ244LiSIexX/Xiw5jxhR0MkNcS0Y/4bx7Qq4Ws3Wmy3bhFbPSmZQh1KRINwOzY32d8Xz72LGwm8VwyFCn9U1Yo8ERan21EKDvcQpdR%40b4/bDm5eRwIbga0hm7Wog7LnDsQ/OggJqP9CMMkZbqMRN881H4sw0ebMfSZyZf448/HIX5Smfr1%409ofCPzQrZ5GpFVCsaftczTiN%40TnVRPsArbUeLDM2eIAXZyd/QbnBTU840UU3KJ0ohvlBvMi7mYgj0u76JTqRqvyjVnqdNQX6yEPu/6F6SUxEaGkcTRp4h9sVTRZ%40aEMMoQ/0p73GahSPB/G6wuJOfT5PBopnSBrspJq5CvCH2dnz5STkc4ZhpUjj2SLxBDxiJLVruNSbri3sY~&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=120

Comment: @KSib Above is the format in which i am getting the access token, now i want to fetch the token from URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uri = new Uri("http://176.66.102.44:8088/#access_token=eHwAIJd%40bo657tdv8XSaS6hYU%40Ov/XiOWBlMdwo4/h63Q1E%40RcJukIbBnDU%40dh/AYJnEQc4/WmTrUCN3snAntvmchEpZ244LiSIexX/Xiw5jxhR0MkNcS0Y/4bx7Qq4Ws3Wmy3bhFbPSmZQh1KRINwOzY32d8Xz72LGwm8VwyFCn9U1Yo8ERan21EKDvcQpdR%40b4/bDm5eRwIbga0hm7Wog7LnDsQ/OggJqP9CMMkZbqMRN881H4sw0ebMfSZyZf448/HIX5Smfr1%409ofCPzQrZ5GpFVCsaftczTiN%40TnVRPsArbUeLDM2eIAXZyd/QbnBTU840UU3KJ0ohvlBvMi7mYgj0u76JTqRqvyjVnqdNQX6yEPu/6F6SUxEaGkcTRp4h9sVTRZ%40aEMMoQ/0p73GahSPB/G6wuJOfT5PBopnSBrspJq5CvCH2dnz5STkc4ZhpUjj2SLxBDxiJLVruNSbri3sY~&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=120");
var fragments = uri.Fragment.Split('&');

string accessToken = null;
if (fragments.Length > 0 && fragments[0].StartsWith("#access_token="))
{
    accessToken = fragments[0].Remove(0, "#access_token=".Length);
}

if (accessToken != null)
{
    // Do something with the token
}
```

How this works is we are going to use the `Uri` class to parse the Url for us. 
The `Uri` class property `Fragment` will retrieve everything after (and including) the `#`, as described in the docs.

We will split on the ampersand because we only need the `access_token` parameter. We don't need `token_type` or `expires_in`. We'll ignore those.

The last part is just throwing the excess data away on the string which is the part that says "#access_token=" so we call `Remove` on the string to do that. This returns a new string to `accessToken` and then you can do whatever you want with the data.

Also, keep in mind this only works if the `access_token` is the first part of the fragment. If it's isn't then after you do the `Split` you'll need to see which index of the array starts with `"access_token="` instead

[Uri Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Uri.Fragment Property Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.fragment(v=vs.110).aspx)